# what's wrong with "ng-repeat" in my AngularJS App?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm stuck with `ng-repeat` of my AngularJS App.
Here is my html mark-up

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in trRecords">
<td><input type="checkbox" value="{{item.chkboxValue}}" id="{{item.chkboxId}}" /></td>
<td>{{item.TicketID}}</td>
<td>{{item.ItemCode}}</td>
<td>{{item.ItemColor}}</td>
<td>{{item.MachineAsset}}</td>
<td>{{item.Capacity}}</td>
<td>{{item.Layer}}</td>
<td>{{item.MaterialQty}}</td>
<td>{{item.PackageQty}}</td>
<td>{{item.StartDate}}</td>
<td>{{item.EndDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

and here is script data

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.BindCutTicket = function () {
var Factory = $('#NewFactory').val();
var CRCode = $('#NewCRCode').val();
var ItemCode = $('#NewItemCode').val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
async: true,
url: 'SearchingCriteriaHandler.ashx?Action=SearchCutTicket&Factory=' + Factory + '&CRCode=' + CRCode + '&ItemCode=' + ItemCode,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
$scope.trRecords = response;
console.log('$scope.trRecords= ');
console.log($scope.trRecords);
},
error: function (response) {
if (response.status === 500) 
Notify('danger', 'Your Session Expired. Please Login Again.');
else Notify('danger', response.responseJSON.Message);
}
});
}; 
});
```

From console.log, I can see the data from the server , but `ng-repeat` doesn't render data on the  tag

I don't know what's wrong.
Could you help me?

Comment: Probably you need to call `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: why use `$.ajax` in jQuery where you can use `$http`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the data property of the response  on success,

```
success: function (response) {  
   $scope.trRecords = response.data;
}
```

Comment: by using `console.log(response)`, i can see the data from server already, not need to use `response.data` since server-side, i return `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CutTickets, Formatting.Indented)`

Comment: so what do you see when you put console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

Use factory like this

```
app.factory('Service', ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        Success: function (id) {
             return $http.get("/api/getSomething/" + id).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                return response;
                //error
            })
        },

    }
}])
```

then in your controller

```
Success(id).then(function (response) {
            if(response.status=200){
                $scope.trRecords = response.data;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, when I work with `$.ajax()` inside angular , if `$.ajax()` has option `async: true`, I start to have the problem. I temporary use `async: false`. I'm not sure, it's real root cause or not but I hope it can be helpful for others.
And thank you for all suggestions.
Thomas.